# Can't call event of element after element is appended

Tags: jquery

I have a problem when using `append()` to add an element. After adding I want to handle the event keypress of this element but it won't work. This is my code:

```
$(...).append("<input class='chat_input'>");

$('.chat_input').on('keypress', function(ev){
     console.log(ev) });
```

Please help me.

Comment: [The code you've posted works just fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/m6L4rrs0/). Please edit your question and make sure it contains an actual repro.

Comment: Provided you are executing those lines in the order shown, there is no issue here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to append your event handler to the document, if you run your keypress handler before you append it won't be added to any appended inputs after.

Here is a jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/z8xcytLq/

jQuery

```
$(function () {

    $('.input').append("<input class='chat_input'>")

    $(document).find('.chat_input').on('keypress', function (ev) {
        console.log(ev)
    });
});
```

Also a global event handler is better as you won't have 6 different handlers for 6 different inputs

Comment: `$(document).find('.chat_input')` is exactly the same as `$('.chat_input')` where the latter is probably a little better optimised. You're still attaching the keypress event handler to the .chat_input element so your mention of a "Global event handler" is also incorrect. The thing you have done w.r.t. the question but not mentioned is add a function around it which jQuery will call once the document is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it this is my code :  $( document ).delegate( '.chat_input', 'keypress', function(ev) {